# Chop in Piecewise function

Tags: piecewise, attributes

I'm trying to implement a complex square root with branch cut on the negative real axis; the (real part of the) second argument determines which branch to take.

```
sqrt[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] = 
 Piecewise[{{I Sqrt[-x], Re[x] < 0 && y >= 0}, {-I Sqrt[-x], 
    Re[x] < 0 && y < 0}}, Sqrt[x]]
```

[image]

This works fine except when during calculations $y$ obtains a small imaginary part. Evaluating

```
sqrt[-1, 1 + 10^-12 I]
```

returns the error

> GreaterEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with 1+I/1000000000000 attempted.

Now I could do the comparison with `Re[y]` instead of `y` and be done with it, but I'd actually like to know about it, if $y$ ever developed a significant imaginary part during my calculations so `Chop[y]` seems more prudent. But adding this to the definition of `sqrt` changes its behavior in no way whatsoever. In fact, the `Chop` doesn't even make it into the output when evaluating

```
sqrt[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] = 
 Piecewise[{{I Sqrt[-x], Re[x] < 0 && Chop[y] >= 0}, {-I Sqrt[-x], 
    Re[x] < 0 && Chop[y] < 0}}, Sqrt[x]]
```

Can someone explain why? Does this have something to do with `Piecewise` not having the attribute `Hold`?

Comment: "Can someone explain why? Does this have something to do with Piecewise not having the attribute Hold?" That seems likely. You could avoid this by using `SetDelayed` (:=) to define sqrt. Otherwise define, `chop[x_?NumericQ]:=Chop[x]` at use the new `chop` instead (which will not evaluate for non-numeric arguments).

Comment: @mmeent And the reason it works with `Re` is because "Re[expr] is left unevaluated if expr is not a numeric quantity."? (See [doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation for `Chop`, "Chop[expr] replaces approximate real numbers in expr that are close to zero by the exact integer 0." Compare

```
Chop[{10^-12, 10^-12 // N}]

(*  {1/1000000000000, 0}  *)
```

Recommend that you use `NumericQ` rather than `NumberQ`

```
Clear[sqrt]

sqrt[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{yc = Chop[y // N]},
  Piecewise[{{I Sqrt[-x], Re[x] < 0 && yc >= 0}, {-I Sqrt[-x], 
     Re[x] < 0 && yc < 0}}, Sqrt[x]]]

sqrt[-1, 1 + 10^-12 I]

(*  I  *)
```

Comment: Good point. I meant to change that a while back but forgot about it in the meantime.